# SELECT query sqlalchemy model

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy model

```
bar = Table(
    "try",
    meta,
    Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("foo", String),
    Column("baz", String),
    info={
        "audit.options": {
            "enabled": True,
        }
    },
)
```

But when I try to run `select` query

```
SELECT * from try WHERE ID=1;
```

It shows an error

```
ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from try where ID=1;
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possibly because you're using capital letters in the model definition, but raw sql ignores them, creating a mismatch. Give it a try

Comment: This works but I have one more doubt that I had to add ```'id'``` field to fetch the row does sqlalchemy does not assign a default ```unique id``` to every row as ```Postgres``` does so that I can fetch any row using that ```Id```.

Comment: id should be unique, but if you specify the id (with an insert), I've seen that sqlalchemy overwrites the existing row instead of adding a new one. With inserts, you do not need to specify the id of the row (it will create the "next" and automatically increment the id correctly)

Comment: Yes the ``` 'id' ``` works fine but as in ```postgresql``` model we don't have to create an ```'id'``` field separately itt automatically creates a ```unique id``` itself which works as ```primary key``` does ```sqlalchemy``` also does that or I will have to keep ```'id'``` field.

Comment: Can't answer that confidently. Honestly, I'd rather read the database's metadata from the existing db and not create models in code, its such a waste of time. Chances are you're not the only one managing that database and your code isn't the single source of truth. Just read the database "as is" and use it. Sqlalchemy can do that very well.